# Colored grep causing trouble when run in subprocess (OS X)

Tags: bash, macos, grep, mv

I'm having troubles in doing simple stuff with grep in my Mac. I'd like to rename a file, and for that I use grep and sed.

- If I don't use `grep`, it works fine.

[image]

- If I use `grep`, it doesn't work: mv shows a weird error.

[image]

For what I understand, the reason may be the *colored grep* I am using, and then `mv` uses **not the filename, but the code for displaying the colored filename** in the console (as `elm` content is a colored `yum.txt`, instead of a normal one).

Is this the reason? What can I do?

Comment: You seem to be right. Check the `GREP_OPTIONS` environment variable (`printenv`) and/or your aliases.

Comment: I have `alias grep='/usr/bin/grep --color=always'` purposely to colorize the results. I have no `GREP_OPTIONS`.

Comment: Then just change `--color=always` to `--color=auto`. If you have the coloring features of grep always enabled, this is what you get.

Comment: That's the answer, @danlor! Write it as an answer to be flagged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, those strange characters are indeed color codes. You can search for the `--color=` option either in `GREP_OPTIONS` environment variable (`printenv`) and/or your user defined aliases.

Then just change `--color=always` to `--color=auto`; with the `--color=auto` option set, `grep` should display color codes only when the standard output is connected to a terminal and plain text otherwise.